# SwiftUI: Binding in initializer: default value

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, binding, combine

Consider the following example:

```
struct TestView: View {
    @Binding private var value: String
    init(value: Binding<String>) {
        self._value = value
    }
}
```

How can I initialize the `TestView` without any `Binding`, i.e. just bind it to an empty string (if the caller doesn't need to connect that property)?

Ideally I'd be able to use the `TestView` like this (sometimes):

```
TestView()
```

I've tried setting a default value in the initializer, but obviously, it fails:

```
init(value: Binding<String> = Binding<Strings>("")) {
```

Any approaches on how to tackle this API issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`constant`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding/constant(_:)) factory method:

```
init(value: Binding<String> = .constant("")) {
    self._value = value
}
```

Now you can do `TestView()`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!